# How to escape java special characters and run Linux commands

Tags: java, linux, escaping

I'm writing a java program to find specific files(files with special permissions and by file type) within the directory. The following command executes properly since there aren't any special characters.

```
find /home/Cnf271/Desktop/ -perm -4000 ;
```

Now if i try to execute the following command using my java program, terminal doesn't give a proper result.

```
find /home/Cnf271/Desktop/ -name "*.txt" -perm -4000 -exec ls -ldb {} \;
```

Java Program,

```
//
        ..
        System.out.print("Please enter directory path: ");
        fileDirectory = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Please enter file type (txt/pdf): ");
        fileType = scan.next();
        filetypecmd = " \"*." +fileType+ "\" ";

        System.out.println(filetypecmd);
        String cmd = "find "+fileDirectory+ " -name "+filetypecmd+" -perm -4000" ;

        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process = run.exec(cmd);

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String space = "";

        while ((space=buffer.readLine())!=null) {

        System.out.println(space);
        ..
        //
```

Program works fine.however, `String cmd` command doesn't give me a proper result because linux command is wrapped with special characters.How do I execute the following command in my java program.

```
find /home/Cnf271/Desktop/ -name "*.txt" -perm -4000 -exec ls -ldb {} \;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the double backslash ``\\`` before the `;` character? I don't see you adding the `;` character in your Java code by the way. Java uses backslash to escape as well, so you may have to "double escape" characters in strings...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  Yes I tried backslash. filetypecmd = " \"*." +fileType+ "\" ";  There are no syntax errors in my java program. I think linux  doesn't execute the command, because it contains other characters such as backslash. Now if I use escape characters to hide java syntax errors,java program works fine.but when the command runs in the linux environment,it doesn't give a proper result. Thanks

Comment: Note: since Java 7 you can read file permissions as well. It would be easy to search for the files [from within Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)), sidestepping the issue (XY problem).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks. but I'm trying to execute the command using linux find command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that need to be quoted (or escaped special characters) for a Linux command shell do **not** need to be quoted when being executed by `Runtime.exec()` (they do not need to be *protected from the shell*).

In your code, remove the extra quotes on the wildcard search parameters:

```
String filetypecmd = " *." + fileType + " ";
```

I tested this and was able to run your code correctly on Linux, but I had to remove your `-perm -4000` parameters to get results in my case. I received **no** results with the extra quotes around `"*.txt"` but all was well without them.

By the way, you can also use a `Scanner` to collect the results:

```
Scanner results = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while (results.hasNextLine())
{
    System.out.println(results.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Also I had add double quotations  in my String cmd to get results. String cmd = "find "+fileDirectory+" -name "+filetypecmd+""+" -perm -4000";